# How to create a Textbox with style that accepts only 2 characters

Tags: html, css

How do i create a html textbox which  looks that it can accepts only 2 characters .

```
<input type="text"  maxlength="2" size="1"/>
```

what style do i need to apply so that textbox can be shown in such way it can accept 2 characters  style ="???"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple width would do:

```
<input type="text"  maxlength="2" size="1" class="twochar"/>
```

And the css:

```
.twochar
{
    width:2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kjl_42/vstMC/